# What are the places where does Ubunty saves recent user activity and tools to clean them?

Tags: zeitgeist, ubuntu-tweak

I'd like to clear (and disable tracking if possible) all the recent user activity tracking (like most recently accessed files (MRU) and applications, thumbnail caching etc.). The only thing I do NOT want to flush is the bash commands history.

I've taken a look at Ubntu Tweak's "Jaintor" section but it is disk space centric (rather than privacy centric) and the only thing of these it cleans is the thumbnails cache (alongside with APT cache etc.).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

[Privacy Indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/indicator-privacy/) lets you clear the recent files list and the Zeitgeist activity journal and optionally disable Zeitgeist (but not the recent file list).

Please file a bug report if you want additional functions to be added.